# how do I print key value pairs each on a separate line

Tags: python, dictionary, printing, line

This is what I am getting:

```py
[('04', 3), ('06', 1), ('07', 1)]
```

This is what I want:

```
04 3 
06 1 
07 1
```

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Well, do you know how to print anything at all? Given `('04', 3)`, can you print `04 3`? Do you know how to repeat code with each element of a list? If you put those pieces together, can you solve the problem? *What actually is the difficulty here*? Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 and note that you are expected to try to solve the problem yourself first. This is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tuple matching and f-string:

```py
lst = [('04', 3), ('06', 1), ('07', 1)]

for x, y in lst:
    print(f"{x} {y}")

# 04 3
# 06 1
# 07 1
```

Comment: Please do not enable people who request code without demonstrating any attempt to solve or even decompose the problem.

Comment: This answer is perfect.  I spent hours on this question, but never thought that print(f"[k} {v}") could do it.